# Angular error when trying to navigate to another route via router navigate?

Tags: angular

On an admin page, I have a logout button that looks like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
```

In admin.component.ts, the logout button is:

```
logout() {
    this._router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
```

When I click the logout button, I get the following error message in the chrome developer console:

`Uncaught (in promise): Error↵Error↵    at Error.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3051:33)↵    at ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3048:35)↵    at injectionError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:5912:86)↵    at noProviderError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:5950:12)↵    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:7451:19)↵    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:7490:25)↵    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:7422:25)↵    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:7291:21)↵    at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:8238:52)↵    at PreActivation.getToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:40056:25)↵    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:40010:48)↵    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:49726:27)↵    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:49716:18)↵    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:23374:18)↵    at ArrayObservable._subscribe (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:49285:28)"`

This was actually working before, but now if I navigate to any route besides the current route I am on, I get this error message.  There error message is cryptic to me, so I am not sure what is causing it.

Comment: can u setup a plnkr to show the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of zone.js are you using? (You can look in your package.json file.)

There was a bug in one of the versions of zone.js that caused it to generate this error, masking the *real* error and making it close to impossible to figure out what is wrong.

At the time, I just back-set the version to a prior version and then the *real* message told me what was wrong.

This error is also sometimes caused by a problem with a service and can be caused when the service is not properly registered (with a component or a module) or not properly injected (in a constructor).

Comment: Hi DeborahK, this is what I have in package.json: ` "zone.js": "^0.7.2"`. By the way, your pluralsight courses are great.

Comment: Thanks! That is very kind!

Comment: Yep, that was it. I upgraded to the latest zone.js and was able to spot the error. Thanks for the help.